# Find the value of $\cos \tan^{-1} \sin \cot^{-1} (x)$ .

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $\cos \tan^{-1} \sin \cot^{-1} (x)$ .

...
Let $\cot^{-1} x=z$
$$x=\cot z$$
Then,
$$\sin \cot^{-1} (x)$$
$$=\sin z$$
$$=\dfrac {1}{\csc z}$$
$$=\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {1+\cot^2 z}}$$
$$=\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {1+x^2}}$$

Comment: Why don't you continue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then we have $$\cos\left(\left(\tan^{-1}\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\right)$$

If $\tan^{-1}\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=y,\dfrac\pi4\le y\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\tan y=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and $\cos y\ge0$

$\cos\left(\tan^{-1}\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)=\cos y=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^2y}}=?$

Comment: I couldn't get how $\dfrac {\pi}{4}\leq x \leq \dfrac {\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @Aryabhatta, As $\infty\ge\sqrt{1+x^2}\ge1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and let $\tan^{-1}y=w$

Then, $$\begin{align}
\ \cos{\tan^{-1}y} & =\cos{w} \\
\ \text{Now since $1 \ge y \gt 0$ we have $\cos{w} \gt 0$}\\
\ &= \frac{1}{\sec{w}}\\
\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2{w}}}\\
\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\
\end{align}$$

And then substitute $y$.

Answer (score 0):

So your final expression is: $\cos\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)$

Now we know that:

$\tan^{-1}p=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\right)\\
\implies\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+{\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)}^2}}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+{\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}}}}\right)\\
\implies\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{2+x^2}}$

Therefore, $\cos\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)=\cos\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{2+x^2}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{2+x^2}}$